# Arch Linux: How to ignore certain packages for certain repositories using pacman?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I have an unofficial repository called `haskell-core`. I want to blacklist every haskell package in `extra` and use the packages from `haskell-core` instead. I don't want to use haskell packages from `extra` and I need it to be low maintenance. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
Pacman still installs haskell packages from `extra` if they are newer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just put your repository above `[extra]` in `pacman.conf`. Your file should look like:

```
[core]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[<your custom repository>]
Server = <your repository location>

[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

In this way your haskell packages will automatically be preferred over the official packages from extra with the same name unless those in extra have a higher version number. 
Be sure that your packages handle all the necessary dependencies of official haskell packages if you don't want to run into trouble. This only works if the custom packages have higher version numbers than the official ones.

Another alternative would be to add `provides=('<[extra] package name')` and `conflicts=('<package name'>)` to your `PKGBUILD`s and then add you repository anywhere in `pacman.conf` so that when you install your packages pacman will ask if you want to replace those in `[extra]`, if they're installed. You custom packages should not have the same name of the official ones. For example, a package should be called `<package-name>-custom` or something like that.

Comment: Pacman still prefers `extra` instead of my unofficial respiratory. Is this because `extra` is slightly newer than my unofficial respiratory?

Comment: yes, pacman prefers the first repo when the `pkgver` is the same or higher, otherwise it prefers the higher `pkgver`. You can use the opther method I added to the solution. I assumed your repo contained newer packages. For an example of this second method see [this](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ha/haskell-x11-git/PKGBUILD) PKGBUILD that replaces `haskell-x11.

Comment: Are there any implications if I automated the second solution above?

Comment: what do you mean with "automated"?

Comment: The addition of `provides=('<[extra] package name')` and `conflicts=('<package name'>)`

Comment: Of  course the content of `provides=()` and `conflict=()` is different for each package, right? Anyway, as long as you `PKGBUILD`s are correct there shouldn't be problems, just check other `PKGBUILD`s from the AUR (as the one I already linked) for comparison, you can find lots of examples there.